# Google Datastudio show empty row combinations

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am creating a Google Data Studio report for a car dealership and I have a problem.

I have made these 3 screenshots to illustrate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you see on the first screenshot, the datasource is pretty simple, used/new indicates weather the car being sold is new or used and if it is a sportscar or family car, and exchange/clean deal indicates weather the dealership takes/buys the customers old car in for a trade off in price. The rest should be self explanatory.

On screenshot2-3 you see my report, I have one table for each salesperson and it shows the amount of sales for each combination that has sales.

The problem is this, I want the tables to show each combination even if it does not have any sales at all, it should just show 0 then in record count. Like Mike on the left has more combinations than john, I still want Johns table to show those combinations just with a 0 then, and it should be sorted the same on each table so they look the same, just different data in the cells.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to make a combination of data, from the database with itself. Your main analysis dimension, which will generate your combinations, is used/new and Exchange/Clean deal. So your combination should be:

[image]

The filter defined in the second database (right base) must contain a filter telling which person the table will be destined for. So, for each table, you must make a new combination that contains the person-specific filter.

I just took a sample from your original database (10 first lines) and the result is:

[image]

Comment: This dosent work, it just duplicate of the rows now instead of counting the same ones together. Can you try adding some more lines from the datasource and see for yourself?

Comment: See these screenshots https://imgur.com/a/1dfFFrt - https://imgur.com/a/0kKeuVo . it duplicates the rows instead of counting up